# Обработка и вывод последних записей из БД

Tags: php, база-данных

Есть БД с некоторым количеством новостей. Мне нужно вывести списком, например, последние 5.

С запросом к БД у меня проблем нет, а вот обработать полученную информацию у меня не получается. Для примера, пусть будет таблица news с 3 строками: id, title, description.

Какой должен быть PHP код для вывода 5 новостей на одной странице?

Comment: Возьмите любой пример работы с базой из php, они на каждом шагу. там как раз циклы по получанным данным. Вот и делаете себе цикл, пока БД данные возвращает и формируете в нем блоки html для новостей

Comment: На самом деле вариантов обработки информации с бд множество. Советую просто почитать что-то вроде php+sql.Много информации и примеров обработки данных полученных из бд. По своему опыту скажу что это зависит от того что вам нужно в итоге. Я лично представлял данные из бд в виде списка и выводил <ul><li>данные</li></ul> без каких либо проблем , но тут некие трудности возникли именно с php кодом. Я советую вам полазить по туториалам типа взаимодействие php и sql и там будет многое что вам поможет , уверяю , по крайней мере помогло мне.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода информации на странице необходимо использовать шаблоны.

В самом примитивном случае шаблоном может выступать отдельный РНР файл, который отвечает за вывод всей информации. Соответственно, в шаблон мы передаем полученные из БД данные.

Соответственно, сачала мы должны получить данные, а потом подключить наш файл шаблон:

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5");
include 'news.php';
```

где в news.php уже и будет осуществляться вывод

```
<div>
<? foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <div>
        <h3><?=$row['title']?></h3>
        <div><?=$row['description']?></div>
    </div>
<? endforeach ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я использовал mysql_connect и mysql_select_db для подключения к БД. Если вставляю ваш код, то получаю фатальную ошибку "Call to a member function mysqli_query() on a non-object".

Comment: Использовать mysql_connect и mysql_select_db нельзя. mysqli_query() использовать нежелательно. Надо прочитать про [PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo) и использовать только её.